# How to remove link rel=canonical from next.js amp page?

Tags: next.js, amp-html, meta-tags, head

Is there any way to remove this metatag completely? It seems to be added automatically, but i need to get rid of it? I'm not using any libraries for meta tags/head handling, but i haven't noticed anything useful in their docs.

Edit: Probably amp for next.js is responsible for this tag

Comment: normally this sits in a file called `index.html`

Comment: it's not present in next.js. I was looking for a part where this could be hardcoded, but it's missing. What may be relevant: this page is using next/amp, but I'm not sure if this would be affecting meta tags like that

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem. We are running nextjs with amp in hybrid mode and want to sometimes not have the  linking to the amp version of a page... Both the amphtml and canonical links are automagically added by next and no obvious way to opt out of that wasn't found. We ended up creating a component for that that was included wherever we wanted. Perhaps this could work for you too?

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'    
function NoCanonicalMetaLink() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.head.querySelector('link[rel="canonical"]')?.remove()
  })
  return null
}

function SomePage() {
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <NoCanonicalMetaLink />
    ...
  )
}
```